# The change data of the updated firestore document in firebase cloud function returns undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firestore onUpdate trigger and trying to get the data of the
updated document (field name, new value).

```
const newValue = change.after.data();

const name = newValue.name;
```

**I expect to notify the user with the new mark added to his profile for example:**

> the new attend mark is 50

But when i display them in the body of the notification it shows:

[image: received notification]

Here is the full cloud function snippet:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
//functions.config().firebase
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('stuThird/{userId}/stuMarks/{markId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const newValue = change.after.data();

      // ...or the previous value before this update
      const previousValue = change.before.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      const name = newValue.name;
      var body = ' the new mark of' + name + 'is'+ newValue;
      if(newValue){

      var message = {
        notification: {
            title: 'new mark changed',
            body:   body,
        },
        topic: 'bebo'
    };
  }

    // Send the message.
    return admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((message) => {
           return console.log('Successfully sent message:', message);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error sending message:', error);
        });
      // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

**

> here is the database:

**
[image: first structure part]
[image: second structure part]

Comment: Add ur database

Comment: There's not enough information here.  We need to be able to see the exact contents of the document that's being updated, and the change you're making to it that triggers this function.  Also, your question should explain what you expect to happen in this function that's different than what you're observing.

Comment: It seems like you're getting back the whole object in both cases instead of the part you want. Please provide us with more info as Doug suggested.

Comment: Doug please see my edit. Please note that am updating one of the three integer values of any document inside stuMarks collection above to trigger the notification